# Excel VBA That command cannot be used on multiple selections

Tags: excel, runtime-error, vba

I have got this code:

```
Worksheets("SOURCE_DATA_HIDDEN").Activate
    Sheets("SOURCE_DATA_HIDDEN").Select
    Columns("B").Copy
    Sheets("RESOURCE_DEMAND").Select
    Columns("C").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

I use it to copy and paste a column from one sheet to another. The code used to work last time i checked and it somehow broke today.
It comes up with the following error:
Run time error 1004: That command cannot be used on multiple selections.

I really cant figure out what is going on. I haven't made any amendments to the code.

Answer (score 0):

try to clear the clipboard `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify that a lot more. If its just the values you are wanting too, change to `PasteSpecial`. Try this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOURCE_DATA_HIDDEN").Columns("B").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("RESOURCE_DEMAND").Range("C1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Eliminates all the selecting and activating, which is generally a habit you dont want to keep!

Comment: Also, forgot to mention, I dont personally like using Columns where they arent 100% necessary so when pasting I have used Range of top cell in Column C. You could just use `Columns("C") instead though. Dont know if it has any major impact on the code, but this way at least seems a little more specific.

Comment: i tried that but it comes up with an error Subscript out of range (runtime error 9)

Comment: What line does it do that on?

Comment: I would also check you have typed the sheet names exactly as well, as that can cause that error.

Comment: comes on line ActiveSheet.Paste . I have already checked the names, plus tried without the underscores (as they do cause problems sometimes) but it still comes up with an error.

Comment: There should be no Activesheet.Paste line. Replace ALL the code from your question with the 3 lines of code from my answer and it will work.